# Problem trying to visualize 3 way interaction in R. Trouble with adding rawdata to ggpredict plot (using ggeffects package)

Tags: r, ggplot2

- I am trying to overlay the raw data points onto my line graph with two panels. I have added a picture of the graph I am getting (incorrectly) below, I am trying to generate only 2 graphs (by overlaying the top row with the bottom).
- I am using the ggeffects package, with ggpredict and plot() functions. For reference, my linear model is as follows:
  `lm(LS ~ gender*age*sleep + sample_2 + sample_3 + sample_5, data = data)`
  Note: gender is binary here.
- The issue arises when I use the plot function, specifically when rawdata = TRUE . Based on the documentation, this should overlay the raw data onto the graphs. However, I get 4 graphs instead: 2 with the ggpredict line graphs (split into 2 facets for each gender ), and 2 scatter plots with the raw data (also split by gender). I would like to combine these by gender.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggeffects/ggeffects.pdf

[IMAGE: Incorrect Graph Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APGMy.png)

Below is the code:

```
model <- lm(LS ~ gender*age*sleep + sample_2 + sample_3 + sample_5, data = data)
gpd_terms <- ggpredict(model, terms=c("age","sleep","gender")) # no problems with `the output here
gp <- plot(gpd_terms, ci = TRUE,
rawdata = TRUE,
dot.alpha = 0.5,
jitter = TRUE,
colors = "gs")
```

As an alternative, I have also tried this with ggplot2 (below), using these instructions https://github.com/strengejacke/ggeffects/issues/110. However, I cannot get this to work when using the geom_point argument. I get the error "Continuous value supplied to discrete scale". I suspect this has to do with my use of gender groupings.

```
gp <- ggplot(as.data.frame(gpd_terms), aes(x = x, y = predicted, colour = group)) +
stat_smooth(method = "lm") +
geom_point(data = attr(gm, "rawdata"), aes(x = jitter(x), y = jitter(response)),alpha = 0.6) +
facet_wrap(\~facet, ncol = 2) +
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), color = FALSE, alpha = 0.2) +
labs(
x = get_x_title(gm),
y = get_y_title(gm),
colour = get_legend_title(gm))
```

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I AM NOT experience in this, but have spent days of my life trying to figure this out:

I was having a similar issue but wasn't trying to separate into "panels" (AKA facets)-  I was just trying to get points to plot over lines on one graph. I can share what worked for me on one panel and you can try to add panels to it. I did get the plot() function to plot and wrap a 2-way interaction for me, I didn't like it though (not much editing can be done to aesthetics).

I ended up using ggpredict() then ggplot() [b/c I used a lmer and wanted specific coloring for lines and data points]. ... When I add "facet_wrap" to my code it only separates the line by group but all of the data is plotted on all 3 plots instead of separating the data out by grouping - I think this is because my data is in a separate dataframe from my prediction lines (problem with ggpredict()).

First try the plot() function because it might work for you:

```
plot(gpd_terms, colors = "gs", facet = TRUE, add.data = TRUE, jitter = TRUE)
```

If that doesn't work / you don't like that, try specifying everything into ggplot() *NOTE I included how to specify all colors

```
#Sorry, I didn't change factor names to your data
#Load libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(ggeffects)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggnewscale)
library(ggtext)
library(tidyverse)

#define model 
model <- lmer( Wine ~ term1*term2 + (1|Sad))

#Make prediction 
pred_interaction <- ggpredict(model, terms = c("term1", "term2"), ci.lvl = 0.95)
glimpse(pred_interaction) #check what it named each factor (changes terms from original data)

# Define color palettes
colors_continuous <- brewer.pal(9, "Blues")[4:9]  # Adjust color range if needed
colors_discrete <- brewer.pal(5, "Blues")[3:5]  # Adjust color range if needed

#Simplified plot interaction lines from ggpredict, points from original data
interaction_plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = pred_interaction, aes(x = x, y = predicted, color = as.factor(group)),  #Line: x, predicted, group from pred_interaction 
  scale_color_manual(values = colors_discrete)) +    #define color for lines, discrete 
  geom_ribbon(data = pred_interaction, aes(x = x, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high, #confidence intervals from prediction
                                           fill = as.factor(group)))
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors_discrete)+ #define color for CI, discrete 
  new_scale_fill()+ #allows you to define new fill after CI fill, so data points can be on continuous scale
  geom_point(data = Test, aes(x = term1, y = Wine, fill = term2), #Adds real data to plot from dataset, not prediction 
             size = 3, shape = 21, stroke = 1, color = "black") #adds outline to data point 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = colors_continuous) + #defines color for data points as continuous
  theme_cowplot()+
  labs(x = "X title", y = "Y title", color = "Color label") 

#View plot
  plot_pointsA
```

Ok if that works and it plots it all on one plot. You may be able to add a facet - IF your data and lines are in the same dataset (I haven't yet figured out how to make panels with grouping factor when data and lines are in separate datasets)

Just add this at the end of the code, hopefully it works!

```
+ facet_wrap(vars(group)) #will group by ggpredict group, might not carry data with it!
```